# Leaving a startup for another and work-life balance

Tags: work-experience, work-life-balance, startup, burnout

First of all, I'm going to start off with a little bit of background.
I'm 22 and graduated almost 2 years ago. I'm a very methodical and precise guy. I like working on analyzed projects and mature things before I push them to production.
I've been working for a startup for one year now and my contract is ending pretty soon.

The reason I'm posting here is because I have become really skeptical about startups and work-life balance around them.
I was approached by another startup this week and they seem really interested in me. I do have to say I like what they're doing because it fits me.

Is it possible in start-ups to "take the lead" and guide people to more best-practices (even with less experience) works ? Or just because they have to grow fast, we'll have to build fast without tests, etc ?

Does working in multiple start-ups really build legit experience in your career ? I mean you'll probably end up failing a lot and he could be good. But I feel like some HR are just looking at what you succeeded in.

Edit: Made it into a more viable post for other people, not just a "should I take the job" post

Comment: Even though this is offtopic, let me caution you: start-ups are start-ups. New, immature companies will always have some amount of chaos associated with them since their processes (and to a lesser degree, interpersonal relations) aren't well... _mature_ yet. Beyond that, new and/or small companies will always have some manner of ***urgent*** thing going on, since these sort of companies don't have the bankroll/goodwill/market-share to suffer delays/mistakes. caveat emptor.

Comment: Problem is, where I'm living, it's really hard to get a job in a bigger company because of qualifications, or experience. They're always looking for sheeps with 5 legs.

Comment: @CinetiK - Something good to learn early about companies - even though they're looking for 5 legged sheep, they'll happily take a normal one. If they asked for normal ones, they'd get 3 legged sheep (or goats!) instead.

Comment: Hey CinetiK, and welcome to [workplace.se]. Thanks for working to [edit] your question, but I think it is still off-topic as-is. Each workplace is going to be different, and there will always be some things you can change, and some you can't. Could you focus on a specific issue you are facing, what you want the outcome of whatever you do to be, and ask on how you can implement that in your workplace? That may end up on-topic. Alternatively, you can ask in [chat] for guidance from our regular users.

Comment: That's what I do, I'm asking for guidance in a startup, on the possibility of "taking the lead", and if it really builds legit/reliable experience for someone.

Answer (score 3):

You said this:

> I like working on analyzed projects and mature things before I push them to production.

I think this means that you're not well-suited at this time to a start-up role.  There might be start-ups out there which are well-analyzed and mature, but those are the exception rather than the rule.  This isn't a poor reflection on you: a job could be a good job, but that doesn't mean that it's the right job for you.

You need to figure out what the right job for you is.  You've learnt that work-life balance is part of it.  Figure out what the rest is, and look for a job that has what you want.  Remember: an interview is just as much about you finding out whether this is a job that you want as it is about the employer finding out whether you are someone who would be a good fit for them.

Comment: From information I could find about their team, it seems that they are way more experienced than at my current job. The CTO I had on the phone was really convincing. He told me about his way of working (Test-driven development, robust code -not just working code-, modularity). And from what I could find on him, it's seems pretty serious but I just don't to be too "naive" again. Maybe there are some questions I should ask before going further (?). I really enjoy the start-up culture, fresh people, etc. I just don't know if that culture fits me.

Comment: @CinetiK Being more organised than that other startup over there is like being less crazy than tom cruise. I wouldn't use that as a yardstick to judge whether or not a place is organised at all. There's nothing wrong with not being suited to the start-up culture in any way. It demands not only a certain type of person but a certain type of lifestyle.

Comment: This is part of what identifying what the right job for you is.  What is it that you like about start-up culture?  How can you find those great things about start-up culture while still getting the work-life balance you crave?

Comment: I love the fact you're kind of free to use/learn whatever technology you want. The fact you're building things that are not common like SAP for a big company.